# How to modify this script so that all of my files are not deleted when trying to delete files that do not have XML files with them?

Tags: python

I am trying to delete all .JPG files that do not have .xml files with the same name attached to them. However, when I run this script, all of my files are deleted in my directory and not just the desired images. How can I change this script so that I can just delete the images without corresponding .xml files?

Note: The only files I have in the directory are .JPG and .XML

```
import os
from tqdm import tqdm

path = 'C:\\users\\my_username\\path_to_directory_with_xml_and_jpg_images'

files = os.listdir(path)

for file in tqdm(files):
    filename, filetype = file.split('.')
    if filetype == 'xml':
        continue

    imgfile = os.path.join(path, file)
    xmlfile = os.path.join(path, filename + '.xml')
    if not os.path.exists(xmlfile):
        print('{} deleted.'.format(imgfile))
        os.remove(imgfile)
```

Comment: FYI, you can use `os.path.splitext()` to get the extension.

Comment: Without a [mre], the best advise we can give is to print both `imgfile` and `xmlfile` and make sure you get the right paths and that they indeed exist

Comment: The logic looks correct to me.

Answer (score 1):

It's hard to tell why your code doesn't work as we don't know the exact contents of the directory. But a simpler way to do what you want could be to use the amazing [`pathlib`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html) library (Python >= 3.4). The method [`Path.with_suffix()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html#pathlib.PurePath.with_suffix) will make the task quite easy, together with [`Path.glob()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html#pathlib.Path.glob):

```py
from pathlib import Path

path = Path('C:\\users\\my_username\\path_to_directory_with_xml_and_jpg_images')

for imgfile in path.glob("*.jpg"):
    xmlfile = imgfile.with_suffix(".xml")
    if not xmlfile.exists():
        imgfile.unlink()
        print(imgfile, 'deleted.')
```